# rails 3.2.2 and rocket_tag no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and have been able to create an app with acts_as_taggable being used for tagging. I'm switching to rocket_tag because you can easily search by tag and active relations at the same time.

I followed the instructions for installation and the correct tables get created. The problem is when I try saving the tags, code is below:

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_taggable :tags
  attr_accessible :description, :start, :tags
```

Then when filling the db with data

```
50.times do
  description = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  start = Date.new(2008,12,30)
  users.each { |user| user.performances.create!(description: description, start: start, tags:["comedy"]) }
end
```

and I get the error below

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: taggings.tags: DELETE FROM "taggings" WHERE 
"taggings"."taggable_id" = 1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Performance' 
AND "taggings"."context" = "taggings"."tags"
```

The models taggable attribute is :tags and the rocket_tag gem is trying to access it as a column of the taggings table.

Any ideas of what to look at next would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

there is a bug in how rocket_tag loads taggings, caused on the latest squeel gem version (1.0.5)

you can either revert squeel to 1.0.1 or use the fixed code from here https://github.com/bradphelan/rocket_tag/issues/16